# Error while importing an API, where as API is getting reflected in api publisher but throwing an error in APIMCLI

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Migrating API from one environment to other environment, where as export is working fine and while importing it is throwing an error besides I can find the APP is getting reflected in API Publisher.

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 6 path $

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 6 path $

Comment: Could you please create an issue in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim-tooling/issues? If it is possible please share the Swagger file. Do you have any special values in the Swagger in the mentioned line?

Comment: Issue resolved .. Checked the Json file with Json validator and made changes. This helped

Comment: Was there any issue in the imported Json?

Comment: When I'm exporting an API it contains api.json, swagger.json and endpoint.json files inside that where as YAML files are not created in this process. I tried manually creating YAML files and placed in the folder, where as in this process the Json might have came up with changes. But the point is, YAML files are created manually which is not a best practice. Need solution for YAML files creation which is done automatically(i.e., while exporting). Any suggestion!

Comment: When exporting an API, you can provide the format of the files, i.e. json or yaml. --format flag should do the trick. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim-tooling/blob/master/import-export-cli/docs/apimcli_export-api.md

Comment: apimcli import-api --file test/Entry_1.0.0.zip --environment dev --params json --verbose     Error importing API Reason: C:\Users\RAVIKU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apim121676907\Entry-1.0.0\Meta-information\api.json\Meta-information\api was not found as a YAML or JSON

This is the error I'm facing @Pubci

Comment: It looks like api.json or api.yaml is missing when exporting. Can u verify that file in the mentioned location. We should check why it is missing during export.

Comment: Yes @Pubci, While I was Exporting an API it is  only creating an .json file but .yaml is missing. Tried with older versions also but the result is same. It worked only when I created an .yaml file manually. Is there anything like I should have active subscription of WSO2 ? And update it through WUM !